# Clarification on the definition for product on a ring quotient

Tags: ring-theory, definition, ideals

I'm going over my notes on ring theory, and have come across the following definition for the product on a ring quotient $R/I$ for $I \triangleleft R$,

$$
(a+I)\cdot(b+I) := (a+I)(b+I) + I
$$

We then claim that this indeed is equal to $ab + I$ making the canonical projection a ring morphism from $R$ to the quotient. I can see more or less immediately that:

$$
ab + I  \subseteq (a+0)(b+0) + I \subseteq (a +I)(b + I) + I
$$

However, for the other inclusion I had written  that:

$$
(a+I)(b+I) + I = ab + aI + Ib + I^2 + I \subseteq ab + I
$$

which I'm now not entirely convinced of it being correct, since $z \in (a+I)(b+I)$ if and only if:

$$
z = \sum_{j = 1}^n(a+x_j)(b+y_j) = \sum_{j = 1}^nab + \sum_{j = 1}^nay_j + \sum_{j = 1}^nx_jb + \sum_{j = 1}^nx_jy_j
$$

for some $x_j,y_j \in I$, and this is in $nab + aI + Ib + I^2$ which may as well not be equal to $ab + aI + Ib + I^2$. Am I computing this the wrong way?

Comment: What is $(a+I)(b+I)$ on the first line (without the dot)? Presumably it's not a circular definition, so is that the set product (i.e. $AB=\{ab\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$)? If so, then the fourth line is incorrect since there is no sum involved, it is just $z=(a+x)(b+y)$ where $x,y\in I$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro we've defined the product $XY$ of two subsets of a ring $R$ as

$$
XY = \left\{ \sum_{i= 1}^nx_iy_i : x_i \in X, y_i \in Y \right\}
$$

so that's why I made the explicit distinction. Is this a non-standard definition?

Comment: @GuidoA. That's the usual definition for the product of *ideals* but it's not the one being used here.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I see. That makes sense, since it coincides for the product of subsets of a monoid in the case of $(R, \cdot)$. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it, since that resolves the issue :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of the product of cosets of an ideal is

$$(a+I)\cdot (b+I)=(a+I)(b+I)+I,$$

where $(a+I)(b+I)$ on the right is the *set product* $AB:=\{ab\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$, not the ideal product $IJ=\{\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i\mid x_i\in I,y_i\in J\}$. Given this, we can show that $(a+I)\cdot (b+I)=ab+I$:

If $i,j\in I$, then $(a+i)(b+j)=ab+(ia+jb+ij)$, where the right term is in $I$ since it is an ideal, and conversely $ab+i=(a+0)(b+0)+i\in (a+I)(b+I)+I$.

(I usually see this done in the opposite direction, where we define $(a+I)(b+I)=ab+I$, and then we must show that this definition does not depend on the member of the coset chosen for the definition, which can be done by rewriting it to $(a+I)(b+I)+I$, where the only thing we need of the set product is that it is a function of $a+I$ and $b+I$ rather than $a$ and $b$.)

If we used the ideal product in that definition, then it would contain $nab$ as you noticed, which is not what we want. In particular it would not be a coset at all if $ab\notin I$, because then it would contain both $0$ and $ab$ and these do not differ by a member of $I$.

Comment: +1 This is exactly why I discourage people from thinking of quotient operations as being defined 'element-setwise'.  It leads them straight into a pit of confusion.